# In Magic, are you allowed to reveal what cards you have drafted to stop others from drafting the same colors?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-drafting, mtg-competitive-rel, mtg-regular-rel, mtg-professional-rel

For example, suppose I open a [bomb Boros mythic]. I reveal it, and say "Ok guys I'm drafting Boros" (with the implication that everyone else should avoid fighting me over those colors). Is this permissible?

If it is not permissible, am I allowed to say "Ok guys I'm drafting Boros" without revealing the card? If this is also not permissible during a draft, can I reveal my preferred colors before the draft?

Comment: To be honest that would not stop me from drafting a color and could make me prioritize that color if I was looking to draft it.

Comment: yeahI'm not so sure that's a sound strategy either. If all other players make just 1 hate pick each because of your reveal, you dont have a deck any more.

Comment: Depends on who you're drafting with. If the other players are either naturally cooperative, or are experienced enough with draft that they know it's in their best interest to be cooperative, it could be pretty effective.

Comment: In any case, there is to consider that there's only five colors, and eight players at the table. Even if you somehow attempt to share equally and fairly, someone *will* be losing out - and if everyone does that math, they might be inclined to deviate from the fair path. Distributing cards by color intentionally seems like it would be a kitchen table format, not something that the existing Draft framework is very suited for.

Comment: @Hackworth Hate picking is generally a bad idea though. The main reason is making your deck stronger is more important than making one of the seven opposing decks weaker. https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/beyond-basics/dont-hate-draft-2016-07-28

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The MTR (Tournament Rules) indicate that you are not supposed to reveal the contents of your booster (which includes your pick); visually or otherwise. You may, however, reveal double-faced cards.

> **7.7 Booster Draft Procedures**
>
> (...)
>
> Players may not reveal the front face of their card selections or the contents of their current packs to other participants in the draft and must make a reasonable effort to keep that information from the sight of other players. Players are not permitted to reveal hidden information of any kind to other participants in the draft regarding their own picks or what they want others to pick. (Exception: This does not apply to double-faced cards, both faces of which may be revealed at any time during a draft.)

The Tournament Rules can be found here: https://wpn.wizards.com/en/rules-documents
An alternative source that provides comments from/for judges is the Judge rules resources: https://blogs.magicjudges.org/rules/mtr7-7/

As for whether revealing your favorite cards before the draft is permissible: The rules don't explicitly disallow it, and of course chatting about your favorite colors for decks before a match shouldn't be a problem. If I try really hard, I can think of scenarios where this *might* fall into collusion or unsporting conduct territory, but you would certainly have to get there intentionally.